# CPU overload on a VPS (Cloud) - overusing resources, how would DC/Host react?

Tags: vps, central-processing-unit

I got a couple of VPS from DigitalOcean. Each of these VPS got one core. I'm running some script for data mining. I often happen to use one core of my CPU in the range of 1.0 - 1.5 apparently, it sounds like I'm over-using what I've been allocated.

I wonder how would the host/DC react to it. If its a normal practice, I would even be happy to use as much as 2.0 on each VPS, thus actually utilizing 2 cores in the VPS.

THanks in advance for any inputs.

regards,

Sam

Comment: Ask your provider. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: Please read the FaQ, this question is off-topic. If you want to know how DigitalOcean would react on this then I suggest contacting them.

Answer (score 1):

Each provider will have their own methods of dealing with what they consider abuse of the resources. You should read their Acceptable Use Policies and Terms of Service to see whether this would be acceptable. Or you could just ask them!